# How to Retrieve value of SUM function in SQL through c#

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a Stored Procedure CalculateTotal to return the SUM of all records in Amount column from Table Spendings

```
`CREATE PROCEDURE CalculateTotal
 @Name varchar(50),
 @Month int
 @year
 As
 SELECT SUM(Amount) As Total
 FROM Spendings
 WHERE MONTH(Date) = @Month AND YEAR(Date)= @Year AND Name = @Name`
```

When I execute this procedure from SQLServer, execution done successfully and returned Total amount,
I need to get value of Total from C#, I tried following code,

```
public void CalculateTotal(string name, int month , int year)
 {
     cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
     cmd.CommandText = "EXECUTE CalculateTotal @Name,@Month,@Year";
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", name);
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Month", month);
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Year", year);
     reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();          
     if(reader.HasRows)
     {
           while (reader.Read())
           {
               int total = (int)reader["Total"];
           }
      }
}
```

when i debug it the 'While' condition is true and when body of 'while' loop executed an error encountered called IndexOutOfRangeException : Total

How can i do it to retrieve the value of SUM function in c#

Comment: Is there a specific reason you are using a stored procedure rather than a function? If you only need to get a sum, function might be easier to write and call

Comment: @Bala Did you try my answer?

Comment: oops, sorry for late reply @ofcoursedude. just for one reason i am using stored procedure, i can easily modify the query even when i run the dll in another system.

Comment: @iJay thanks for your answer. i tried it but the returnParameter returns 0 while i watch in debuggin, but actual value to be returned is 100.

Comment: @Bala It works fine with me, check again if you interested. I have made some small changes

Comment: I meant a SQL function rather than SQL stored procedure. Although they are similar, SQL functions are intended to return a scalar value, which is very much your case. You'll then avoid having to do the reader thing and instead use cmd.ExecuteScalar to just get that one value you are interested in.

Comment: @ofcoursedude. Thanks dude.. M young to this programming, i dont know what SQL function you meant, i would like to learn those function, if Possible share the link in which i can know about those functions to return scalar value.

Comment: start here https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(FUNCTION_TSQL);k(SQL11.SWB.TSQLRESULTS.F1);k(SQL11.SWB.TSQLQUERY.F1);k(MISCELLANEOUSFILESPROJECT);k(DevLang-TSQL)&rd=true

Comment: @iJay could you please let me know what changes to make in code. i will attach a snap of the screen. Thats the output of query, Return value refers to 'return_value'. when i search about that line i got when the procedure exceute success it will return 0, The same value is i am getting in the c#, so what changes shall i make for the 'Return Value' to refer the 'Total'.

Answer (score 1):

When returning a single value from SQL Server via ADO I suggest you use ExecuteScalar. An example of the usage :

```
    Int32 total= (Int32)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

Please also have a look at implementing the using pattern to ensure that you are not causing a memory leak.

Comment: Thanks for your information. This one worked for me when i change the casting method to " Int32 total = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar()); "

Answer (score 1):

May be try something like this.

```
public void CalculateTotal(string name, int month , int year)
 {
     cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
     cmd.CommandText = "CalculateTotal";
     cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", name);
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Month", month);
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Year", year);
     connection.Open();
     string result = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
     connection.Close();
}
```

Comment: Got Result, This one worked, i needed to return Integer, so i just type cast it.

Answer (score 0):

Change your procedure;

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE CalculateTotal
 @Name varchar(50),
 @Month int
 @year int
 @Total int Output
 As
 BEGIN
 SELECT @Total = SUM(Amount)
 FROM Spendings
 WHERE MONTH(Date) = @Month AND YEAR(Date)= @Year AND Name = @Name
 END
```

You need to add return parameter to the command:

```
public void CalculateTotal(string name, int month , int year)
 {
     cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
     cmd.CommandText = "CalculateTotal";
     cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", name);
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Month", month);
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Year", year);
     var returnParameter = cmd.Parameters.Add("@Total", SqlDbType.Int);
     returnParameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
     int total = (Int32)cmd.ExecuteScalar(); 
}
```

Comment: Very Thanks iJay, its working, But it return 0 for "total = (Int32)cmd.ExecuteScalar()". and i tried with "total = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar())" now it returns correct value. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I tried the code with the example shown below:

```
SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand();
cmd2 = con.CreateCommand();
cmd2.CommandText = "gettotalprice";
cmd2.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ordernums", ordnum.Text);
string result = cmd2.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
Label2.Text = "<b>Total Amount= </b>" + result + " Rs.";
```

It worked for me all fine with no problems and I got the total amount.